# Where can I download php_dbase.dll?

Tags: php, dbase

I need to read DBF databases but I didn't find **php_dbase.dll** in php.net (I only found the .c sources).
Could someone provide me the link to download this DLL ?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right place to download it is http://pecl.php.net/package/dbase.

Comment: dead link. seems to no longer work